# Query builder "addSelect" affects "addOrderBy"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder, doctrine-query

I have Symfony 4 width Doctrine, two entities/tables with relation Fixture (one) - Picture (many). Both tables has column with name "order".
I am loading (eagerly) all fixtures and its pictures. I am trying to sort query result only by root entity.

It's working as expected when not using "addSelect" function.

```php
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('fixture');
$qb->innerJoin('fixture.pictures', 'pictures');
$qb->addOrderBy('fixture.order', 'ASC');
```

The result is:

```sql
SELECT f0_.name AS name_0, f0_.color AS color_1, f0_.`order` AS order_2, f0_.id AS id_3, f0_.valid_from AS valid_from_4, f0_.valid_to AS valid_to_5, f0_.disabled AS disabled_6 FROM fixture f0_ INNER JOIN fixture_picture f1_ ON f0_.id = f1_.fixture_id ORDER BY f0_.`order` ASC
```

But when I change it to

```php
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('fixture');
$qb->innerJoin('fixture.pictures', 'pictures');
$qb->addSelect('pictures');  //eager loading
$qb->addOrderBy('fixture.order', 'ASC');
```

I am getting:

```sql
SELECT f0_.name AS name_0, f0_.color AS color_1, f0_.`order` AS order_2, f0_.id AS id_3, f0_.valid_from AS valid_from_4, f0_.valid_to AS valid_to_5, f0_.disabled AS disabled_6, f1_.id AS id_7, f1_.`order` AS order_8, f1_.file_name AS file_name_9, f1_.file_path AS file_path_10, f1_.fixture_id AS fixture_id_11 FROM fixture f0_ INNER JOIN fixture_picture f1_ ON f0_.id = f1_.fixture_id ORDER BY f0_.`order` ASC, f1_.`order` ASC
```

I am really not sure why is there "f1_.`order` ASC". I also tried it with

```php
$qb->addOrderBy('pictures.order', 'ASC');
```

and for this case it's working (it's sorted only by pictures).

TL;DR;
When using "$qb->addSelect('pictures');" in query builder, extra order by ", f1_.`order` ASC" is added in SQL query even only root entity should be sorted. It's working when "addSelect" is not used or when query is sorted by joined table 'pictures.order'

Comment: In your entity files, do you have any ORM "OrderBy" annotations?

Comment: Thx, that's it. I totally forgot about it as I am not used to use it.

Answer (score 0):

@ehymel was right. I had @ORM\OrderBy annotation used in Entity "Fixture" and forgot about it.